# Eager Loading using EF6 Fluent Api with a Composite Key Fails to Load Related Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, eager-loading, ef-fluent-api

I must be creating the `composite key` incorrectly or connecting it to the `related entity` incorrectly. I can get it to work in a simplified scenario of a single key, but the `composite key` fails. I'll show both working and non working versions.

**My classes:**

```
public class Parts {
   public string PartID { get; set; }
   public string Revision { get; set; } 
}

public class InstanceHistories {
    public int HistoryID { get; set; }
    public string PartID { get; set; }
    public string Revision { get; set; }
    public virtual Parts Part { get; set; }
}
```

**Fluent API - That works**

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Parts>().HasKey(p => new { p.PartID });

 modelBuilder.Entity<InstanceHistories>().HasKey(i => i.HistoryID);
 modelBuilder.Entity<InstanceHistories>().HasRequired(i => i.Part);
```

**Repo call**

```
history = await repo.All
                    .Include(b => b.Part)
                    .Where(i => i.PartID== partIDToSearch).ToListAsync();
```

This repo call will load back my related Part object without any issues.

When I change the Fluent API to make the part have a `composite key`, my repo call will no longer return the `related entity`.

**Non working Fluent API update**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parts>().HasKey(p => new { p.PartID, p.Revision });
```

I have tried a few different scenarios of `.WithMany()`, `.HasForeignKey()`, `.HasOptional()` but nothing really seems to kick the Part back. I even tried to `Lazy Load` and they wont return so I know something must be up with my setup. Has anyone come across this scenario?

**Edit**

Even when I force the SQL to be shown (ie  `uow.Context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;),` I see the related entity appear in the joined result.

Also, I do not receive any errors. Just null return on the Part object.

Comment: The posted sample model and configuration are fine. Tested in a clean environment (latest EF6.1.3, SqlServer db), everything works as expected (the `Part` property is populated). Something has to be different in your real scenario. Without providing reproducible sample, I don't see how we can help.

Comment: Oh interesting... I'll rebuild on a clean setup to see if I get the same result. Thanks @IvanStoev

Comment: Are you running a migration after you change the key?

Comment: Not running any EF migrations.

Comment: Have you setup the composite key on the parts table in the database?